# Detecting a multiple of a number

Tags: game-maker

First time posting here so I'm not completely sure how this goes, but a friend told me to post my problem here, so here goes.

I'm using Game Maker 8.1 for a simple project, and I've come to a halt due to not knowing how to find a multiple of a variable.

I currently have this code:

```
if step = 941 || step = 941 + 205*1 || step = 941 + 205*2 || step = 941 + 205*3 || step = 941 + 205*4
{
    alarm[0] = 1
}
```

"step" is a variable that an object is adding +1 every frame.

Now what I want to do is that this function fires itself when the step variable is either 941, or 941 + any multiple of 205 (as in 205, 410, 615, 820, etc)

I tried using the mod function (%), but

```
if step = 941 || step = 941 mod 205
{
    alarm[0] = 1
}
```

didn't work, so now I'm stuck.

I really don't feel like putting every 205 manually, but I'll do it IF there's no other option.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax of Game Maker, but mathematically I think what you want is: if (step - 941) mod 205 = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Game Maker but mod returns the remainder of a division. 941 isn't a multiple of 205 so the test wouldn't act the way you intend for it to. Subtract 941 from step so that you're left with 205 * n which you can then check to see if mod 205 results in 0 (no remainder means it's a multiple).

Something like this, maybe:

```
if (step - 941) mod 205 = 0
{
    alarm[0] = 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon! You just saved me a butt-ton of time :D